# google protobuf timestamp undeclared identifier with C++ on Windows

Tags: c++, protocol-buffers, grpc

I have a Windows native C++ project that uses google protobufs (version 3 syntax) and gRPC. I have a .proto file that includes the Timestamp type like this:

import "timestamp.proto";

I can successfully generate (using protoc.exe) the .cc and .h files for the messages and services in my .proto file without any errors or warnings. I can also generate the output for gRPC from the .proto file without errors or warnings.

When I use those generated files in a Visual Studio project, I see these errors in the .cc file generated from my .proto file. They're all related to the Timestamp type:

```
Error C2491 'scc_info_Timestamp_google_2fprotobuf_2ftimestamp_2eproto': definition of dllimport data not allowed
Error C2491 'TableStruct_google_2fprotobuf_2ftimestamp_2eproto::offsets': definition of dllimport static data member not allowed
Error C2653 'PROTOBUF_INTERNAL_EXPORT_timestamp_2eproto': is not a class or namespace name
Error C2059 syntax error: '<'
Error C2065 'scc_info_Timestamp_timestamp_2eproto': undeclared identifier
Error C2065 'scc_info_Timestamp_timestamp_2eproto': undeclared identifier
Error C2039 'descriptor_table_timestamp_2eproto': is not a member of ''global namespace''
Error C2065 'descriptor_table_timestamp_2eproto': undeclared identifier
```

I've added the Timestamp.pb.h/.cc files to the Visual Studio project header files, as well as the other .h/.cc files generated from my .proto file.

I have no idea how to go about troubleshooting this. I've verified that removing the Timestamp type allows the project to build successfully. I've tried an older version of protobufs. And of course googled for hours...

My environment:

```
Windows 10
Visual Studio 2017
vcpkg (Microsoft C++ package manager) used to build Protocol buffers 3.11.3 and gRPC 1.27.1
```

Any suggestions?

Answer (score 2):

I've found the resolution for this problem. It was mostly caused by my include folder path. I the VS include path set to "\include\google\protobuf" which has all of the .h files generated from .proto files. What I needed was to have the include folder just set to "\include". This allowed me to change my .proto file so it references the Timestamp type like this:

import "google/protobuf/timestamp.proto";

instead of the way I was referencing it:

import "timestamp.proto";

In addition - I found that I did not need to include "timestamp.pb.cc" in my project. I haven't fully investigated why this is yet - but a couple tests appear to show that it's really not needed.